# Is there a way to force a jQuery UI menu submenu to always position up instead of down?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

I have a simple jQuery UI menu with a header bar over the top:

```
<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 100px;"></div>
<ul id="menu" style="width: 100px;">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu").menu();
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uW44Y/

Is there a way I can force the submenu from Item 3 to **always** open up from it's heading instead of down?

[image: menu]

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/89Wpf/ ?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward, why would you not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery UI menu API supports a `position` attribute: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position. Try something like `$("#menu").menu({position: {my: 'left bottom', at: 'top right'}});`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [`position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position) option to setup the position of the submenus.

Ref:

> Identifies the position of submenus in relation to the associated
>   parent menu item. The of option defaults to the parent menu item, but
>   you can specify another element to position against. You can refer to
>   the jQuery UI Position utility for more details about the various
>   options.

jQuery UI position: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Code:

```
$("#menu").menu({
    position: {
        my: 'left bottom',
        at: 'right bottom'
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/89Wpf/